# Python Parse GitHub File

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

I am looking for more information regarding parsing files in Python, specifically from someone's GitHub. For instance, if Person A has a GitHub account with a file with the contents:

```
name = Person A 
my script = scriptA.sh
script output = yarn output
my other files = fileA, fileB
```

I would want to be able to access this information and store with my Python script.

This is not for a class or anything so I am struggling to find good, clear, beginner level information going over concepts like this. Does anyone have any advice here? I have basic parsing and Python understanding, but I want to advance this. Here is some pseudocode I am using to try to brainstorm.

```
def parseAddFile(filename):
   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
   lines = file.readlines() # this should read all the lines of the file
   dict_of_contents={} # this will then put the contents into a dictionary 
   for parameter in line
       name =
```

etc...

Just looking to grow my knowledge, not asking for answers only.

Comment: you want to download scripts from GitHub and then store these scripts into a one large python file ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a Question and Answer site and as such we expect clear questions which we can answer. As your post currently stands, it doesn't have a question which is answerable in our format. You seem to be headed in the right direction. What you call "pseudocode" looks too much like actual python code. I suggest you step back from the python syntax and try to describe the steps to solve your problem **in words**. When you can do that, it will be much easier to translate those words into Python. Also read [ask] for some tips on improving your question.